# A space that is not homeomorphic to itself

Tags: general-topology

I read the following sentence in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_topology#Scott_Topology). It is the second one in the paragraph.

> ... a $T_0$ topological space which is homeomorphic to itself and exhibits pointwise convergence...

Isn't every space homeomorphic to itself? The identity mapping is a homeomorphism, to point one.

Comment: I too am confused. The identity mapping is always continuous.

Comment: Sounds like we should change Wikipedia.

Comment: So somebody wrote something odd on wikipedia. Disaster! http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: Guess: the topological space is homeomorphic to a proper subset of itself. Another possibility is that there is a nontrivial homeomorphism from the space to itself.

Comment: … or that homeomorphisms act transitively on the space? Or that the identity is the *only* homeomorphism of the space with itself? The possibilities are endless.

Comment: You may be abbreviating the quote too soon.  Perhaps the author is describing a homeomorphism $(X, \tau_1) \cong (X, \tau_2)$, where there are two (seemingly) different topologies on the underlying set?

Comment: @SammyBlack, the text being quoted is completely incomprehensible, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ivan : Take a look at the "Talk" page of the Wikipedia article and see if anyone has complained about this.  You can sign up to be a Wikipedia editor and post on the Talk page or even edit the article yourself.

Comment: @Stefan: The [wikipedia] tag is not good, it's quite bad -- since it's not a mathematical tag per se. In any case, please avoid introducing new tags (and even more so when those are meta-tags) without discussing it on the meta site first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an extremely badly worded sentence. On p.157 of *Encyclopedia of General Topology* (Hart, Nagata, Vaughan), they describe Scott topology, and mention that Scott constructed "continuous lattices" that are homeomorphic to their space of self maps $[L \to L]$. Here's the relevant excerpt (I believe fair use allows me to quote a sentence from a book):

> [...] The category of domains and Scott continuous functions is Cartesian closed, and Scott produced a canonical construction of continuous lattices $L$ which have a natural homeomorphism onto the space $[L \to L]$ of continuous self-maps; in such a $T_0$-space as "universe", every "element" is at the same time a "function" whence expressions, like $f(f)$, are perfectly consistent. [...]

This is also the main point of Scott's paper *Continuous lattices* (which you can find online):

> The main result of the paper is a proof that every topological space can be embedded in a continuous lattice which is homeomorphic (and isomorphic) to its own function space.

---

To address the self homeomorphism thing, yes, of course, the identity is always a self homeomorphism. But what can happen is that you have two different topologies on the same set, and then the identity will not be a homeomorphism. But this is unrelated to what's happening in this article.

Comment: I'd say that extremely badly worded sentence is an understatement; extremely badly worded article is, in my opinion, nearer the mark. +1 for still finding what was probably meant by this sentence.

Comment: The article is a mess.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very well organized. It's too bad, the original writer obviously put a lot of effort in it.